# How to create and set a variable in azure data factory v2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How do I set an variable of type array of strings in ADF v2 so that I can iterate over each element?  Each element represents a database name?

The 'Set Variable' activity has a dropdown but displays 'no results found'?

[image: screen shot]
Many thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

from the official doc:

> Use the Set Variable activity to set the value of an existing variable
>   of type String, Bool, or Array defined in a Data Factory pipeline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity

You'll need to use the pipelines Variable first:

[image]

You can also find a good tutorial in here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6136/azure-data-factory-pipeline-variables/

Comment: Azure says I'm using version 2 but my screen is slightly different - see my update

Comment: did you read my answer? You should define pipeline variables, then it will be available in the set variable activity

Comment: and the difference is because my first screenshot, the activity was not selected

Comment: Okay, in my pipeline with nothing selected the headings in the bottom panel are "general, parameters, variables, output".  With the parameters heading selected in the bottom panel I have my variable of type array with a value of ["db1","db2"].  If I then drag the 'Set variable' activity onto the same screen and click the 'variables' heading the dropdown has 'no results found'?

Comment: can't you define db1, db2 as an array variable in the pipeline tab?

Comment: I have a video as well but haven't worked out how to upload

Comment: yes that's what I've done but I get different results, let me upload the video somewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202606/discussion-between-james-and-thiago-custodio).

Comment: ah it works if I add a variable (as opposed to a parameter)